# XPath Expressions - find elements without specifying the entire path

Tags: xpath

I am doing some screen scraping with a library that takes XPath expressions and noticed that several pages are similar, but different.

Is there a way to loosely say "get me divs that have class='mytarget' but exist as a child of a div with class = 'nav' and the exact path is unknown between nav and mytarget."

`<div class="nav">`

`<div>`

`??????`

`<div class="mytarget"></div>`

`??????`

`</div>`

`</div>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, using the `descendant-or-self` axis (`//`):

```
//div[@class='nav']//div[@class='mytarget']
```

Or, if there can be more than one class name on those elements, then this is even better:

```
//div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' nav ')]//
      div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' mytarget ')]
```

**Warning:** this can be very inefficient on large documents. You should use absolute paths wherever the structure is known. Only resort to `//` when the structure is unknown.

Answer (score 0):

Thats what "//" expressions are for. Something like:

```
//*[@class="nav"]//*[@class="mytarget"]
```

http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp

Comment: this will give not div tag but any tags that have these class names